# Concatenating two nested lists based on a single value without using placeholders

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, nested, concatenation

I have nested list that looks something like this:

```
ar1 = [
    [
        '---- a ----',
        'p',
        'q'
    ],
    [
        '---- b ----',
        'm',
        'n'
    ]
    ]

ar2 = [
    [
        'i',
        '---- a ----',
        'j'
    ],
    [
        's',
        'r',
        '---- b ----'
    ]
    ]
```

I need to write a python script that appends the values based on the value that starts and with 4 hyphens. Basically expecting an output like this:

```
liop = [
    [
        '---- a ----',
        'p',
        'q',
        'i',
        'j'
    ], 
    [
        '---- b ----',
        'm',
        'n',
        'r',
        's'
    ]
    ]
```

Previously the value with hyphens used to be the first value all the time which made me write script like this:

```
ar1len = len(ar1)-1
ar2len = len(ar2)-1
if(ar1len < ar2len):
    for i in range(0, ar1len):
        if ar1[i][0] == ar2[i][0]:
            ar1[i] = ar1[i] + ar2[i][1:]
    for i in range(ar2len,(1 + ar1len)):
            ar1[i] = ar1[i] + ar2[i]
else:
    for i in range(0, ar2len):
        if ar1[i][0] == ar2[i][0]:
            ar1[i] = ar1[i] + ar2[i][1:]
```

Now the hyphen values in the input list are coming in different places and this snippet doesn't work. Any pointers to solve this issue are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Your expected result is sorted to swap `r` with `s`. So I will use sorting.

You mention nothing about duplicates so perhaps a sorted set may be ok.

```
liop = [sorted(set(*[ar1[0] + ar2[0]])), sorted(set(*[ar1[1] + ar2[1]]))]
```

If you do not want behavior of set and instead use of append and possible sort then this may be ok.

```
liop = [[''], ['']]

def merge(lst, index, sort_lst=False):
    for item in lst[index]:
        if item.startswith('----'):
            liop[index][0] = item
        else:
            liop[index].append(item)
    if sort_lst:
        liop[index].sort()

for index in range(2):
    merge(ar1, index, True)
    merge(ar2, index, True)
```

The 3rd argument to `merge()` is True to sort, else you can set it to False.

Both of the above sorted returns:

```
[['---- a ----', 'i', 'j', 'p', 'q'], ['---- b ----', 'm', 'n', 'r', 's']]
```

Comment: `item[:4] == '----'` might be more robustly written as `item.startswith('----')` then if your target criteria changes - you don't have to remember to update your slicing to work... (plus it avoids creating a slice)

Comment: @Jon Clements, your advice used in an edit of the answer. Thanks.